# using compass with RVM and installed native ruby?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm, ubuntu-14.04

I am facing a issue with RVM and installed ruby debian/ubuntu package.

As long as I have **only** installed RVM every works fine. I can use the ruby version which is provided/installed by RVM. Also if I install a gems package compass everything works fine. The RVM is installed as recommended by RVM as single user.

As soon as I install a ruby ubuntu package (which is mandatory for some other ubuntu packages and I have not a option to remove it) my RVM configuration is broken. I cannot execute anymore the compass (command not found) also trying to install it once again with

```
gem install compass
```

I am getting

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
   Permission denied - /var/lib/gems
```

Also

```
which ruby
which gem
```

Points to /usr/bin and not to my home?!?
Even if I have set

```
PATH=/home/rocky/.nvm/v0.10.38/bin:/home/rocky/.rvm/bin:...
```

I have no clue where to take a look since I am very new to ruby and to RVM. Hope someone can help me?

Comment: So, try to reinstall rvm.

Comment: where is your rvm installed? Shouldn't the default path be `.rvm` instead of `.nvm` ?

Comment: @shivam, the .nvm is confusing. I tried to say with it, .rvm is nearly at the beginning of the PATH declaration

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting Permission denied - /var/lib/gems

`/var/lib/gems` is owned by `root` therefore you need to do:

```
sudo gem install compass
```

> `which ruby` Points to /usr/bin and not to my home?!? Even if I have
>   set

This is probably because rvm is not running. Try this:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
which ruby
```

Note: Once rvm is loaded correctly, `which ruby` will point to different location and first question may no longer persist (and so do using `sudo`).

Comment: shivam, as noted the RVM is installed in user environment (single user) and therefore it has not to be be root owning.
the source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm is already in the path and appended by either .bashrc or by .profile

Comment: I understand that, but if you see my answer using `sudo` is before loading rvm, because essentially the error message there is independent of rvm. Obviously once you load rvm correctly, that error will disappear.

Comment: maybe a more clearer question. Why is the default ubuntu ruby preceding the RVM ruby, even if the PATH tells to use first .rvm path? This why I am so confused. How and there is a different configuration about ruby/rvm?